# lambda with graphql and sqs send 2 messages to sqs in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-sqs

i'm working on project where i need to write a lambda function which provides AWS API to handles GraphQL query and send the payload to AWS SQS everything is working fine but when i check my AWS SQS queue it shows 2 messages every single time instead of 1 and cloud watch also shows function trigger only once. below i'm sharing my code with you any help would be very much appreciated.

index.js

```
const { graphql } = require("graphql");
const { schema } = require("./graphql/schema");

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // getting query from lambda event
    const query = event.query;

    // getting query variables from lambda event
    const variables = event.variables;

    return await graphql(schema, query, null, null, variables);   
};
```

sqs.js

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1"});

// Create an SQS service object
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion: '2012-11-05', "accessKeyId": process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID, "secretAccessKey": process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY});
const QueueUrl = process.env.SQS_QUEUE_URL;

const sendPayloadToSQS = message => {
    const params = {
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(message),
        QueueUrl
    };

    await sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Message sending failed : ", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Message queued to SQS successfully : ", data.MessageId);
        }
    }).promise();

};

module.exports = sendPayloadToSQS;
```

graphql mutation file

```
const { GraphQLNonNull } = require("graphql");
const { mutationWithClientMutationId } = require("../../common");
const { JobRequestEventResponse } = require("../jobRequestEventResponse");
const { JobRequestInput, JobEventMetadataInput } = require("../jobSchema");
const sendPayloadToSQS = require("../../../sqs");
const { newId } = require("../../../newId");

const JobRequestEvent = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: "JobRequestEvent",
  inputFields: {
    eventMetadataInput: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(JobEventMetadataInput),
    },
    eventInput: {
      type: new GraphQLNonNull(JobRequestInput),
    },
  },
  outputFields: {
    JobRequestEventResponse: {
      type: JobRequestEventResponse,
    },
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: async (params) => {
    const new_id = newId();
    if(params.eventInput.jobId === null || params.eventInput.jobId === undefined) {
      params.eventInput.jobId = new_id; 
    }
    const payload = {
      _id: new_id,
      transactionId: new_id,
      name: params.eventMetadataInput.name,
      userRole: params.eventMetadataInput.userRole,
      date: params.eventMetadataInput.date,
      languageCode: params.eventMetadataInput.languageCode,
      eventInput: params.eventInput,
    };

    //send payload to sqs
    await sendPayloadToSQS(payload);

    return {
      JobRequestEventResponse: {
        id: payload._id,
        transactionId: payload.transactionId,
        status: "Success",
      },
    };
  },
});

module.exports = {
  JobRequestEvent,
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read the documentation again and found the callback is the root cause of my problem: if I provide a callback to `sendMessage` it triggers my function and after when I write promise() again it triggers my function so I remove the callback only as you can see below.

Refer : [AWS Official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html#sendMessage-property)

Instead of this:

```
await sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Message sending failed : ", err);
        } else {
            console.log("Message queued to SQS successfully : ", data.MessageId);
        }
}).promise();
```

I write this:

```
const request = sqs.sendMessage(params);
const result = await request.promise();

if(result) {
    console.log("Message queued to SQS successfully : ", result.MessageId);
} else {
    console.log("Message queued failed");
}
```

Comment: Please add the solution here rather than writing the thanks message.